# Can geoserver limit layer access to clients by credentials?

Tags: geoserver

I have 2 clients which don't want to host geoserver on their systems and use my server.
Since I can encode their js , is there a way to limit the workspace for each client do other can't call it using wms ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, Geoserver support authentication by action (WMS/WFS read and wrtie), by layer and by workspace.
You could use basic authentication, there are few questions on this site on how to integrate it in Javascript
[Geoserver manual](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/layer.html)